# Disable transparency for a "desktop" child window

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, gdi

I pin a window to the desktop by making it a child of the WorkerW window that contains the desktop FolderView in Windows 7 Aero. So far this works perfectly for pinning the window to the desktop, but the window has some sort of transparency which it doesn't has as a topmost window.[Instead of a dark background RGB(0,21,32) the actual desktop background/wallpaper shines through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlBVT.png)

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &cr);
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
    SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0,21,32));
    FillRect(hdc, &cr, (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
```

The client area is drawn via GDI, i tried everything i could think of to make the window fully opaque: SetBkColor, SetLayeredWindowAttributes, WNDCLASSEX.style = CS_PARENTDC, using RGBA colors (only works to get even more transparency up to 100%, but setting it to opaque doesn't change the outcome)

**Is there any way to draw an opaque window as a child of the Aero desktop?**

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't even a supported way to create a child window for the desktop. But if you insist that you must Hack The Planet™, consider creating the window without a redirection bitmap (`WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP`) and manually add a DirectX surface for rendering. That *might* give you more control over desktop composition. Or maybe you can use the DirectComposition API to control desktop composition, although I have no experience with that.

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this unsupported thing? Do you realise that you are not supposed to do this?

Comment: Why make it a child?  What problem does that solve that simply placing the window causes?  Have you considered how this will work under Remote Desktop?  With Aero switche off?  With Windows 8, 8.1, and 10?

Comment: Why should this be "unsupported"? Didn' read anything about it in the docs. It's afaik the only way to pin a window to the desktop, placing it at the z-order (bottom) does not work reliably, see: Openhardwaremonitor gadget, Rainmeter, or even if you dare to still use it, the Windows 7 sidebar.exe. So if even the Microsoft executable struggles with pinning a window at a specific z-order, i didn't see another way of doing it. It doesn't have to work for 8-10. If anyone can contribute a way to pin a window at a specific z-order, then i will gladly implement it ;-)

Comment: @IInspectable Isn't DirectComposition Win 8 or newer only?

Comment: *"Why should this be "unsupported"?"* - Because cross-thread parent/child relationships are not supported by Explorer (see [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)). And yes, DirectComposition was introduced in Windows 8, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Direct2D does the job as intended (100% opaque), as soon as i mix it with GDI (CreateDCRenderTarget or ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget) the whole transparency thing comes up again. So much for "Direct2D and GDI Interoperability"
Guess it's time to port the legacy GDI code to Direct2D then ....

Comment: btw. i tried every combination of the pixelFormat (DXGI_FORMAT & D2D1_ALPHA_MODE) i could find in the documentation and it didnt change the behaviour as long as GDI was involved, so if no one comes up with a solution for GDI, the Direct2D approach seems to be the only "answer"